# R Changing Legend on GGPLOT that has been gathered

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I am struggling to add a modified legend to my ggplot.

I have a data set:

```
birdspp smallsaplings   mediumsaplings  largesaplings
95      5.044642857     2.384615385     1.30952381
97      3.482269504     1.873684211     1.390625
63      6.285714286     2               2.4
57      5.216216216     1.666666667     1.125
```

Which I've created a graph with:

[image: Graph]

Using the code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
    
 sapling %>% 
   gather(sapling_type, mean_number, -birdspp)
      
 sapling %>% 
     gather(sapling_type, mean_number, -birdspp) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(mean_number, birdspp)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color = sapling_type)) + 
       geom_smooth(aes(group =sapling_type, color = sapling_type, fill = sapling_type), method = "lm", show.legend=FALSE) + 
       labs(x="Mean Sapling Density", y="Number of  Bird Species") + 
       theme_classic()
```

As you can see the legend is not very neat.

I've tried turning show.legend = FALSE on and adding this:

```
+ scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Sapling Size",
                            breaks=c("smallsaplings", "mediumsaplings", "largesaplings"),
                            labels=c("smallsaplings", "mediumsaplings", "largesaplings")) +
      scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Sapling Size",
                            breaks=c("smallsaplings", "mediumsaplings", "largesaplings"),
                            labels=c("smallsaplings", "mediumsaplings", "largesaplings"))
```

But haven't had any luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does the "legend is not very neat" mean? What's the desired output?

Comment: As in 'smallsaplings' has no space between the words in the key. Same problem with the others too. Ideally I'd like the title removed as well.

Comment: It would be easier to make specific suggestion if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. But you should leave off the `show.legend=FALSE` but keep the `scale_color_discrete` but change the values in `labels=` to the names with spaces.

Comment: The input data is at the top there? Apologies I'm a bit of a newbie with this. I had already tried that and get the error:  Error in +scale_colour_discrete(name = "Sapling Size", breaks = c("smallsaplings",  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed the data earlier. My answer should work correctly.

Comment: No problem. Thank you that works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 sapling %>% 
     gather(sapling_type, mean_number, -birdspp) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(mean_number, birdspp)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color = sapling_type)) + 
       geom_smooth(aes(group =sapling_type, color = sapling_type, fill = sapling_type), method = "lm", show.legend=FALSE) + 
       labs(x="Mean Sapling Density", y="Number of  Bird Species") + 
       theme_classic() +
       scale_colour_discrete(name="",
           breaks=c("smallsaplings", "mediumsaplings", "largesaplings"),
           labels=c("Small Saplings", "Medium Saplings", "Large Saplings"))
```

[image]